# gmail api batch behalf user

Tags: api, gmail

i'm developing a massive script that perform operations through a Gmail API service account, i use `setSubject` for setup right user for every operation:

```
$client->setSubject($userId);
```

Works well, but i would to improve performance using batch, i tried this flow:

```
   $client->setUseBatch(true);
   $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

   $client->setSubject($userId1);
   $req = $client->createDraft();
   $client->batchAdd($req, 'draft1');

   $client->setSubject($userId2);
   $req = $client->createDraft();
   $client->batchAdd($req, 'draft2');

   $results = $client->batchExecute();
```

2 Drafts are created, but obv. only for $userId2 (last setSubject executed).

for bypassing problem, in this way i can create aggregate actions for same user and execute it...

But if i want execute one batch for `$userId1` and `$userId2` there is an alternative?

Thanks,
Davide

Comment: There is nothing to do with a batch-file in your question.